# Textbox on my calculator not taking in multiple values

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a calculator app. The problem I have run into is that when I press a button on my calculator the value of the button appears onto the textbox. But as soon as another button is pressed it erases the previous value and puts in the new one. How can I fix this so that it shows multiple values?

JavaScript Code:

```
var buttonValue = document.querySelectorAll('button');

for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
  document.querySelectorAll('button')[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML
    displayText(buttonInnerHTML);

  })
}

function displayText(currentKey){
   var activeButton = document.querySelector('input')
   activeButton.value = currentKey;
 }
```

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calulator.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='calulator-border'>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="text-box" value="0">
    </div>

    <div>
      <button class='btn'>1</button>
      <button value="2">2</button>
      <button value="3">3</button>
      <button value="+">+</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button value="4">4</button>
      <button value="5">5</button>
      <button value="6">6</button>
      <button value="-"> - </button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button value="7">7</button>
      <button value="8">8</button>
      <button value="9">9</button>
      <button value="*">*</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button value="0">0</button>
      <button value="/" class='operator-division' style=''>/</button>
      <button value="=" class='operator-euqals'>=</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button class='clear-button'>C</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="calulator.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *concatonate* the value, right now you are *overwriting* it with each new entry passed. `activeButton.value += currentKey;` will add the next entry to the last entry. So when you press 4, it will add 4, then when you press `+` it will add + to 4 `4+`, then press 8, it will add 8 `4+8` and so on, until you press something that needs to evaluate the strings you entered.